# How do I match deep into a hash with Rspec and get reasonable matching errors?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm in a situation where I'm writing Rspec expectations that look like this:

```
expect(result['data']['register']['registered']).to be(false), result.inspect
```

The problem is that most often, the error I get when something goes wrong is:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I found this better way of writing it:

```
expect(result.dig('data', 'register', 'registered')).to be(false), result.inspect
```

which at least shows the result of `result.inspect`, but I imagine there would be something better, such as:

```
expect(result).to dig('data', 'register', 'registered').and be(false), result.inspect
```

I thought about using `hash_including` but I couldn't make it work. I tried:

```
expect(result).to eq(hash_including("data" => {"register" => {'registered' => be(false)}}))
```

or

```
expect(result).to eq(hash_including("data" => {"register" => {'registered' => false}}))
```

or

```
expect(result).to eq(hash_including("data" => hash_including("register" => hash_including('registered' => be(false)))))
```

or

```
expect(result).to eq(hash_including("data" => hash_including("register" => hash_including('registered' => false))))
```

or `includes` by doing:

```
expect(result).to include('data' => {'register' => {'registered' => false}})
```

or

```
expect(result['data']).to include('register' => {'registered' => false})
```

None of which work and the second is horribly verbose... even the first one is not as good as `dig` in my opinion, but I digress.

Comment: hi your question is turning into an opinion - you've shared the matchers you're using but not the output which is what you seem to care about.  What output are you looking for exactly, please share the hash going in, the match you want to make and the output you'd prefer for a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [hash_including](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments)?

```
 a = {a: 2}
 c = {b: 4}
 expect(a).to eq(hash_including(c))
```

Here's the output:

```
expected: hash_including(:b=>4)
got: {:a=>2}
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I updated the question with that.

Comment: what is `be(false)`?  Do you need another matcher there or is `false` enough?

Comment: I just need to match false